# Can an aircraft on loan in the US be based outside the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, faa-approval

I'm interested if there is any possible way to get an aircraft (Piper Navajo Chieftain) on loan for a US citizen and then base the aircraft outside the USA?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to loan an aircraft in the US and then base it outside of the US? I updated the question accordingly. If you wanted to know something else, please edit again to clarify.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly.....

Answer (score 2):

Any US-registered aircraft can be based in any country subject to that country's rules. Just check with your local aviation authorities in the country where you want the aircraft to be based **before you reposition the aircraft**. Some may require you to depart the country every so many days/weeks/months, sometimes in as simple a way as a short hop across a border, but to my knowledge most don't have any restrictions.

Comment: Just make sure it’s allowed by the loan agreement and insurance!

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about a financial loan, but yes, insurance covering it would be a good idea. Insurance doesn't allow or disallow as it can't stop you from doing things that are not covered. It just means you are on your own.

Comment: I get it, just offering a little unsolicited business/legal advice.  Because while the FAA may not care, Avemco or the owner sure might.

Comment: AVEMCO has no say whatsoever on where an aircraft can be operated, only on when they will pay a claim.

Comment: Kinda my point…

Comment: Consider as well that there is no law against having multiple insurance coverages for anything. You can have a policy that covers an aircraft operating in the US, and have a different one that only covers the aircraft while operating in EMEA because the coverage is cheaper for that region of the world.